# Navigation and routing between components using buttons in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to navigate to another component whenever the "Send Questions" button is clicked.

This was my attempt:

```
<p>
  {(this.state.hide) && (
    <button 
      style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}
      onClick={()=> {this.props.history.replace('/questions')}}
    >
      Send Question
    </button>
  )}
</p>
```

However I get the following error

```
Search.js:115 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Following are my imports related to routing

```
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: Maybe just use the <Link/> from react-router-dom like this <Link to="/questions">About</Link> and declare the route in your router?

Comment: @davidbucka I want to use buttons instead of links

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you didn't wrap your component **withRouter**

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       ... 
       <button onClick={() => this.props.history.replace('/questions')}>
       ...
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

> Another simple solution where you don't need to use **withRouter**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default YourComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <p>
        { this.state.hide && (
          <Link to="/questions">
            <button 
              style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }} 
            >
              Send Question
            </button>
          </Link>
        )}
      </p>
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

> Also note: if you want to **replace** the current URL you should use **this.props.history.replace** but if you want to navigate the User to a new page (which is what you most likely you want to do. You should use **this.props.history.push** instead)